# Prove, that the sum difference of all consecutive prime numbers from $p_1$ to $p_n$ is $p_n-p_1$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, prime-numbers

Example: $\mid (2-3)+(3-5)+(5-7)+(7-11)\mid =11-2=9$

I tried a couple of basic tricks to reach some proof but I failed.

Comment: Hint: telescope.

Comment: @achillehui If the user knows that "telescope" means then this post wouldn't exist.

Comment: "**Hint: telescope?**" Would you please clarify? @achillehui

Comment: @achillehui also, it's telescopic sum, not just telescope :)

Comment: @kaster Ok thanks, seems like I have to google it. Pedro is right.

Comment: I think your original question should say the sum is equal to p_{n} - p_{1}, rather than p_{n} - 2.  2 isn't necessarily in the list of primes from the wording.  e.g. 3,5,7 -> |(3 - 5) + (5 - 7)| = 7 - 3, not 7 - 2.  Unless p_{1} means 2, p_{2} means 3, etc.  In which case nevermind.

Comment: @TimClark Thanks for the suggestion, I'll edit.

Answer (score 2):

In general, given any $a_1,a_2,\dots a_n$:

$$(a_1-a_2)+(a_2-a_3)+\cdots (a_{n-1}-a_n) = a_1-a_n$$

That's because re-arranging it:

$$a_1+(-a_2+a_2) +(-a_3+a_3)+\cdots ((-a_{n-1}+a_{n-1})-a_n$$

Comment: You don't need the sequence to be increasing, though.

Comment: Yeah, I was originally going to do it with absolute values, but changed my mind. Will fix.

Comment: Sorry I'm a noob but what does $a$ mean in $a_1, a_2...a_n$ @ThomasAndrews

Comment: It just means a sequence of values, with $a_1$ the first, $a_2$ the second, etc., with $a_n$ the last value. @user18724 $a$ doesn't mean anything. It could be $b_1,b_2,\dots, b_n$. Or $q_1,\dot,q_n$ or whatever. It is purely notation.

Comment: Alright, got it! So, you are saying that the sum difference of any integer sequence is $Lastvalue-2$? Even if the difference of one value to other is not constant? @ThomasAndrews

Comment: @user18724 In general, since the $-a_2$ and $+a_2$ cancel, the $-a_3$ and the $+a_3$ cancel, etc, so it will wind up being $a_1 - a_n$. For your example, $a_1 = 2$ and $a_n$ = 11, but you're taking the absolute value; $|a_1 - a_n| = |2 - 11| = 9$. It won't work like this for general integer sequences, only those that telescope, and the sum will be "First value - Last value"

Comment: It's $Lastvalue-firstvalue$, not $lastvalue-2$. @user18724

Answer (score 1):

The sum telescopes $\ (\color{#c00}{11}\ \overbrace{ -\ 7)+ (7}^{0}\overbrace{\, -\, 5)+ ( 5}^0\overbrace{\, -\, 3)+ (3}^{0} -\,\color{#0a0}{2})\ =\, \color{#c00}{11} -\color{#0a0}{2}$

i.e. inner neighboring terms sum to $\,0\,$ so the sum collapses to the sum of the first and last term.